# Flashcard app store questions and answers

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, core-data

I am creating a very simple flashcard app. It is a very basic app, the initial screen asks users to select a language. From there they pick from 5 categories. After selecting a category the user should get a random question (out of 20 possible questions).

My question is I want a question to not show up again within that set of 20 until all the other questions in that set have been shown. Similar to a deck of cards where the viewed card goes to the bottom of the deck.

The second question is what framework would be best for this application. There are 200 questions in total, all text, no images. My inclination would be to use something like core data or would that be overkill?

Any help on how to best implement this would be appreciated! I've attached a picture for further clarification.[Storyboard Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTEdt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a great job so far.

There are many ways to track your cards. The simplest might be to add a Boolean property to the card definition. Call it something like "hasBeenAnswered" and set it to false. As a card is retired you can set this to true. Refresh your data source after a correct answer by removing the card from your data source and also setting the book to true, or simply set it to true and replace your data source with all cards which are set to false. (Perform the same fetch you used to get your initial set of data: all cards where hasBeenAnswered is false)

On your second question I'd try to learn Realm. It's easier to pick up than core data, and as a cross-platform tool, you can leverage what you learn on iOS if you ever try to develop on mac or android platforms. 
You can also refactor the project to core data after it works the way you want to. And learn even more.

The suggestions I've made are not the most resource efficient, but you won't have any performance issues given the size/scope of your project.

Good luck